# How to close a webform IN C# LANGUAGE?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I simply want to close an aspx Web Form (that is to say to CLOSE THE CORRENT WINDOW).

I saw a lot of explanations that use a Response.Write with Javascript code, but I will not use

them, because I want to know if the C# language offer the possibility itself to close a Web

Form.

QUESTION: How can I close a Web Form with C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

C# is used as a server programming language in ASP.NET

C# runs on the web server that has nothing to do with your browser.
To close the browser window you should use a clientside language like javascript.

Answer (score 6):

That's not possible. C# runs on your server, JavaScript on your client. So the only suitable solution (I'm aware of) is to send a JavaScript `close` to the client.

Answer (score 2):

Your C# runs *only* on the server.  It spits out HTML (and maybe JavaScript), then it's done.  There's no way to close a window without JavaScript.  At most, you might find a C# method that outputs the `window.close` JavaScript for you.  That doesn't buy you much, though.